# c# picturebox point to filesystem

Tags: c#, picturebox

i have a picture box in my win forms app. the question is, how can i make the image load from a directory within that application,

for example, i have a program and it lies under Debug directory. Now i have an image located under Debug/source/images/logo.png. I dont want to make use of resources file (embedded within the assembly)

How can i point it towards that path, instead of getting the image/picture from the local resources file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
String.Format(@"{0}\myDesiredPath\MyFile.MyExtension",System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this, you can use the ImageLocation property or the Load method to specify the path just take a look at the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx)